# Java Applet getImage gives null pointer exception

Tags: java, image, applet, nullpointerexception

I'm making an applet based game in Java, but I'm running into a problem. I'm getting a null pointer exception with the following stack trace:

```
at java.applet.Applet.getAppletContext(Applet.java:204)
at java.applet.Applet.getImage(Applet.java:274)
at ImageEntity.load(ImageEntity.java:84) <==lowest code written by me
at SpriteTest.<init>(SpriteTest.java:14)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:795)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:724)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:380)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The code at ImageEntity.java line 84 is as follows:

```
image = applet.getImage( getURL( filename ) );
```

Using a test print, `applet` isn't null, nor is `getURL( filename )`.

Printing `getUrl( filename )` returns `file:/home/glenn/Documents/code/RMGame/RMPatrolGame/house7.gif`.

Why am I getting a null pointer exception?

Comment: What does geturl return

Comment: I'm guessing that getUrl(filename).getContent() would also fail.  This is likely a problem with the URL returned being incorrect (likely null) or the file being inaccessible.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @mikeslattery The test print of `getUrl(filename)` returns `file:/home/glenn/Documents/code/RMGame/RMPatrolGame/house7.gif`.

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong when I wrote that comment.  I wrote it before I researched the AppletPanel source.  My answer below reflects my opinion now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code for java.applet.Applet.getAppletContext(Applet.java:204):

```
public AppletContext getAppletContext() {
    return stub.getAppletContext();
}
```

'stub' is null.  `AppletPanel.runLoader()` calls [setStub()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#setStub%28java.applet.AppletStub%29).

Your code is calling `getImage` before the Applet has had a chance to initialize (i.e. stub is still null).

Call `getImage()` in the init() method.  Do not call it in a constructor or during field initialization.